# Windows 8.1 hosted wireless network use TKIP instead of CCMP

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-ce

I can start and stop Windows hosted wireless network using commands;

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mySSID key=myKey123456
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Created network uses 'Authentication: WPA2-Personal' and 'Cipher : CCMP' . I can not connect to this network using my handheld device which is using 'Windows CE OS 5.2' and Fusion wireless software. Wireless profiles support TKIP and AES ciphers for WPA2-Personal.

How can I set cipher or Authentication type of Windows Hosted Network?

Comment: But "CCMP" _is_ AES.

Comment: Somehow the device can not connect to it. If I can change security to TKIP or WPA instead of WPA2, probably device will connect. This is development and test environment, top security is not required.